# Printing portions of booklets

Tags: adobe-indesign

I printed a booklet to see how it was coming in the physical world, and show it to somone else.  8 pages in indesign, two covers and 3 spreads, automatically printed with the right pages on the same physical sheet when I used "print booklet...saddle stitched".

Well, I didn't see any option boxes for specifying just the odd sides, etc. so how to manage that? I learned that it prints the sheets in a front-back order so I have to feed one sheet only, wait for that, refeed it upside down and dismiss the error, for every page.

What would make sense is to print one side, pause for me to flip the whole out tray back into the input and hit  once.

Meanwhile, I wanted to re-print just one sheet. The page-selection box refers to booklet pages not sheets, and giving a rage makes them lay out into a new sub-booklet, which is utterly useless.

Is there any guide or deep wisdom for printing booklets on a home printer?

Comment: Just to make things absolutely clear: you’re printing on a printer that _doesn’t_ support two-sided printing, right? That’s why you’re having trouble. The _Print booklet_ option is meant for printing environments where the printer can automatically refeed and flip the page, so everything looks right. If your printer has a booklet feature, you may want to try doing it with that instead.

Comment: Right, my photo printer (Epson R1900) doesn't have a page flipper collate thing.